# Multer buffer is null when using memoryStorage

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to handle uploaded files on an Express route. I would like to write the buffer to a base64 string for storage. However, when using the `memoryStorage` option or [not specifying any options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#multeropts), which is supposed to keep the file(s) in memory and not write to disk, the `buffer` property on the object is always `null`:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
. . .

app.post('/', multer({ storage: storage }).single('photo'), function(req, res) {
    var photo = req.files.photo || req.file || null;
    if (photo) {
        console.log(photo);
        var data = photo.buffer.toString('base64');
        . . .
    }
});

// Result of console.log
{
  fieldname: 'photo',                                                                                                                                         
  originalname: 'me.jpg',                                                                                                                                     
  name: '71a7e8c6aa262063574ddca9538c5174.jpg',                                                                                                               
  encoding: '7bit',                                                                                                                                           
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',                                                                                                                                     
  path: 'C:\\Users\\alsoi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\71a7e8c6aa262063574ddca9538c5174.jpg',                                                                       
  extension: 'jpg',                                                                                                                                           
  size: 16563,                                                                                                                                                
  truncated: false,                                                                                                                                           
  buffer: null
}
```

I have tried JPG, PNG and Text files, but the result is always the same.

I came across [this issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/337), which was never resolved. Am I mis-configuring the multer somehow? Or do I just need to save it to disk and then read it async to base64 it? Ideally, I'd like to just use the buffer that multer is supposed to have created.

I'm using Node 5.11.1, Express 4 and multer 1.2.0 on Windows 10 for development.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling multer inside of your function instead of as middleware?  I like doing it this way so that I can have more control over the error message.

```
var uploadFile = multer(
  {
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  })
  .single('photo');

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  uploadFile(req, res, error => {
    if (error) { // handle error }
    var photo = req.files.photo || req.file || null;
    if (photo) {
      console.log(photo);
      var data = photo.buffer.toString('base64');
      . . .
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That results in: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` for me.

Comment: That's odd.  Looks like your response is getting sent twice for some reason.  Are sending the response outside of the uploadFile method and again inside of it?  Also, is the file.buffer there now?